# Defeat vs Victory

Tags: word-usage, nouns

I recently heard a news report about a football match, which spoke of "Arsenal's defeat of Chelsea by three goals to nil".

Can the word "defeat" be used in this way? (BTW Arsenal won the match 3-0)  - it strikes me as odd/incorrect, because if they just said "Arsenal's defeat", I would take it to mean Arsenal lost. By sticking "of Chelsea" on the end, does it turn it around?

Surely they should have said, "Arsenal's victory over Chelsea"

Comment: It says Arsanal's defeat of Chelsea, not Arsenal's defeat by Chelsea. I think the preposition 'of' makes it clear who is defeated and who is the winner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/defeat#americanheritage) gives two definitions of ***defeat*** as a *noun*. Note the example given in definition (a):

> a. The act of defeating an opponent: *the home team's defeat of their
> rivals.*
>
> b. The state of being defeated; failure to win: *the home
> team's defeat by their rivals.*

Answer (score -1):

I agree, "Arsenal's victory over Chelsea" seems the right way to go. I haven't heard of the verb Defeat being used in this way.